# Yii2 set db connection at runtime

Tags: php, database, dynamic, yii2

In my Yii2 (basic application) web.php I configure a NULL db connection as 2nd database connection.

This needs to be filled with valid parameters which are coming from a record on the main db connection:

```
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
'db2' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => NULL,
    'username' => NULL,
    'password' => NULL,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

After initializing the app() i need to fill out the NULL parameters with values that i retrieve from another database to further use it in models.

How can i achieve this in Yii2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No problem, it is supported

```
\Yii::$app->db2->close(); // make sure it clean
\Yii::$app->db2->dsn= 'yourdsn';
\Yii::$app->db2->username = 'username';
\Yii::$app->db2->password = 'password';
```

Done, now you can use it

```
Yii::$app->db2->...
```

**Another way:**

```
$connection = new \yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => $dsn,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
]);
$connection->open();
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post')->....;
```

Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfect. I'm using the 1st approach. Now i can do in my models which need only access to the "other" database : public static function getDb() { return Yii::$app->db2; }. This will pull it from the right DB then. As a side not, i've moved all models for the "other" database into a seperate namespace. I think i could also extend ActiveRecord seperately for this namespace, but the getDB in there and then extend all models in that namespace off that AR class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using first one and its working fine.