# Yii2 Giving ActiveRecord Model Database Details on Construction

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2

I am construction a login system for Yii2 that can create the identity from either within a table in the Yii2 application or from data from an external database, the data could reside in one of many, many databases.

I know i could setup second, third, fourth databases in the apps config, but it doesn't fit the use case as, as the database belongs to a user who could change it, etc.

What i need to do it instantiate an ActiveRecord model passing it the database details of the database it should connect to, to query.

I have managed to very much confuse myself over this, in trying to work out the correct way to do it.

I know you can pass a config array to the constructor, but am unable to understand how i should do it, should i create and object of \yii\db\connection and pass it to the __construct?
If so how do i then perform the connection ?

I have searched all over for similar use case, but am unable to discover anything that helps, even a pointer would be great.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after so more head banging and searching in a different way, i have discovered a very simple and sensible approach, and the answer does come from SO.

[Yii2 set db connection at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554390/yii2-set-db-connection-at-runtime)